# Get Text From DOM object. Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, dom, text

I have page https://somepage in internet. Here is part of it's code from chrome code:

```
..............
<div class="wr">
<div class="auth_username">tesеDom@mail.com</div>
<div class="auth_stars">
<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-fw">
...........................
```

I have seen many answers and examples, but my code still not working. Seems I am missing something. My manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Bot_copy",
    "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "icons": {
"48": "48x48.png",
"128": "128x128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "https://mypage.my" ],
    "js": ["helloWorld.js"]


    }],

    "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "alarms",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "bookmarks",
    "contextMenus",
    "contentSettings",
    "downloads",
    "history",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "browsingData",
    "proxy",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "storage",
    "tabCapture",
    "notifications",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "<all_urls>",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "debugger"
    ],

    "browser_action": {
"default_title": "Open"
  },
    "background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]    
  }
}
```

content script

```
    window.onload = function() {
    sendMessage();
    }

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    sendResponse({
response: "Message received"
      });
    });

    //Send message to background page
    function sendMessage() {
//Construct & send message
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({

            whattodo:"get_authname"
}, function(response) {

});
    }
```

background

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    var name = document.getElementsByClassName('auth_username').value;
    alert(name);
sendResponse({
    response: "Message received"
});
    }
);
```

I received alert "undefined".

Have no idea. Really strange there are no properly documentation I don't understand object document.

Seems I miss how to use documentc object. I tried also document.getElementsByTagName('auth_username'), but it also not working. Which way is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access DOM from background script. You can access DOM from content script only. so try to place following code:

var name = document.getElementsByClassName('auth_username').value;
alert(name);

in contentscript and it works.